# Artificial Intelligence - Machine Learning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I'm just finishing my reading of the Artificial Intelligence a modern approach 3rd Ed. by Perter Norvig. I used this book mostly as an introduction, and to learn more about the general concept of AI. I'll soon start in a machine learning study group with one of my professors and I'd like to know if anyone knows some good books to learn more about Machine Learning (especially Neural Nets, but not just it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some extracts from the reading list of [a course I finished recently](http://ibug.doc.ic.ac.uk/courses/machine-learning-course-395/):

#### Core Textbook

[Machine Learning](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Etom/mlbook.html) by Tom Mitchell, McGraw-Hill Press, 1997

#### Neural Networks

D. Chen and P. Burrell, '[Case-based reasoning system and artificial neural networks: A Review (pdf file)](/media/uploads/documents/courses/CBR+ANN-2001.pdf)', in *Neural Computing & Applications*, vol. 10, no. 3, pp. 264-276, 2001 (Copyright 2001 Springer).

M.F. Valstar and M. Pantic, '[Biologically vs. logic inspired encoding of facial actions and emotions in video (pdf file)](/media/uploads/documents/ICME06-ValstarPantic-FINAL.pdf)', in *Proc. IEEE Int'l Conf. on Multimedia and Expo (ICME '06)*, Toronto, Canada, July 2006 (Copyright 2006 IEEE Press).

S. Petridis and M. Pantic, '[Audiovisual Discrimination between Laughter and Speech (pdf file)](/media/uploads/documents/ICASSP-2008-PetridisPantic-FINAL-CAMERA.pdf)', in *Proc. IEEE Int’l Conf. Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing (ICASSP’08)*, pp. 5117-5120, Las   Vegas, USA, April 2008 (Copyright © 2008 IEEE Press).

#### Excellent Books

*[Pattern Classification](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0471056693.html)* by R.O. Duda, P.E. Hart, and D.G. Stork, John Wiley Press, 2005.

[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/cmbishop/prml/) by Christopher Bishop, Springer, 2006

Answer (score 5):

You may want to check out these free online courses:

- [Introductory Machine Learning course](http://work.caltech.edu/telecourse.html) by Caltech (starts 3rd Apr,
  2012; lasts 8 weeks)
- [Introduction to Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) by Coursera (should start soon but no date announced yet; lasts 10
  weeks)
- [Introduction to Machine Learning](http://www.ml-class.org) by Coursera (finished; lasted 10 weeked)

Answer (score 3):

[Elements of Statistical Learning](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/)

This book (there's a free PDF available in the link webpage) is an excellent and nearly exhaustive review of the field of machine learning. I know this sounds a bit presumptuous, but it's that good.

By the way, even though the book of Norvig and Russell is very good, it provides next to nothing on machine learning. So, the PDF will be a tough read if you are not sure of your math background.

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at this book, I have a medium foundation on mathematics, I've taken some courses in uni. Well thanks I'll take a look at the PDF